# NoSuchMethodError for getDisplay() while trying to use Listview inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I am trying something fairly complex which may also be a bad practice but I still want to get it done. I am trying to create a CardView navigated through a RecyclerView. I have let the card part for later and right now I am trying to use the contents of each card as a RecyclerView item. Each Item has inside a Checkbox and an ListView (I read though is bad practise to use one inside the other) and each list item has checkboxes. I have created an adapter for the RecyclerView which calls the adapter of the ListView. The data to be displayed are in a json form. I am getting a "NoSuchMethodError" for the getDisplay function.

Here is the code for the RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class CheckoutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckoutAdapter.OrderViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private JSONArray tableOrders;

public CheckoutAdapter(Context context, JSONObject tableOrders) {
    this.context = context;
    try {
        this.tableOrders = tableOrders.getJSONArray("orders");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_checkout, parent, false);
    return new OrderViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        holder.populateOrderList(tableOrders.getJSONObject(position));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tableOrders.length();
}

public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CheckBox checkBox;
    ListView orderList;

    public OrderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_checkbox);
        orderList = (ListView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_list);
    }

    public void populateOrderList(JSONObject order) {
        try {
            checkBox.setText(order.getString("order_id"));
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
            OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(context, order.getJSONArray("items"));
            orderList.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for the ListView Adapter:

```
public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private JSONArray orderItems;

public OrderAdapter(Context context, JSONArray orderItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderItems.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    JSONObject temp = null;

    try {
        temp = orderItems.getJSONObject(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0; //we aren't going to use this. Tags items for easy reference.
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    String item = "";

    if(view==null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_layout_checkout_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.orderItem = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.order_item);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    try {
        item = orderItems.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.orderItem.setText(item);
    holder.orderItem.setChecked(false);
    return view;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox orderItem;
}
}
```

Here is how i call the Adapter in the main activity:

```
    checkoutView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.checkoutRecycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager checkoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    checkoutView.setLayoutManager(checkoutManager);
    CheckoutAdapter checkoutAdapter = new CheckoutAdapter(this, orders);
    checkoutView.setAdapter(checkoutAdapter);
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.georgepamfilis.e_orders, PID: 16475
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDisplay(Landroid/view/View;)Landroid/view/Display; in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/data/com.example.georgepamfilis.e_orders/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_3380ad634bd296e5176d79eb685c23c2473c5017-classes.dex)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2457)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15860)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3142)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3150)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1822)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7530)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the .xml file for the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.georgepamfilis.e_orders.Activities.CheckoutActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/table_name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/table_name"
    android:id="@+id/checkoutRecycler"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the .xml file for the RecyclerView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/order_checkbox" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/order_list"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/order_checkbox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, here is the .xml file for the items of each ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/order_item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am new to this so I may have messed up something basic, or understood something wrong. I would be glad if you could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error seems to somewhere else than the code you've posted. are you trying to access getDisplay method anywhere in your project?

Comment: No, the getDisplay method is called internally, in the RecyclerView java code. When i click on the first line of the error code where it says RecyclerView.java:2457, it opens up the RecyclerView.java code and the problem is in the line 2457 where this takes place:                         
Display display = ViewCompat.getDisplay(this);

Comment: Besides there is no reference to my code in the error message. This probably means that the problem is neither the syntax nor any type incompatibility. It's probably something structural.

Comment: Yes exactly, it seems some structural error which is related to calculating view position on display while rendering. and I am also not sure about whether using ListView inside RecyclerView will work or not. Can you share your reason for doing so?

Comment: I am trying to create a list of cards, where each card corresponds to an order, that is to say a list of order items, which are to be displayed in the card. I suppose there are other, less complicated ways to do that, which I am going to try in case I don't get to the bottom of this. I chose this approache because it seemed more easy to create onClickListeners for each of these items when I used a ListView.

Comment: Ok, so what I am understanding is you're trying to implement nested list. For that you can try some other not so complicated way. One of them is https://github.com/msahakyan/nested-recycler-view